# Toggle sibbling's child's class on input select with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, input, toggleclass

Given the following HTML structure:

```
<input class="addon-thumb" type="checkbox" name="foo"/><label for="foo"><img class="addon-thumb" src="" title="bar" alt="foo"/></label>
```

And using JQuery, how do I toggle the class of the img inside the label tag to be "selected" when the checkbox is selected?

It doesn't matter if it retains the other class (addon-thumb) or not, as long as if the box is deselected it would get that class back.

**EDIT:**
I have tried both of the below suggestions inside `$(document).ready(function(){});` and for whatever reason this is not working for me. I was actually doing something very close to the below in the first place. Any more help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by img 'selected'?

Comment: Are you getting a javascript error in the console?

Comment: It was very late when I wrote this. There was an obvious mistake... `image` must be `img`. Try again :) (@box9 did the same mistake).

Comment: Haha, I thought it looked wrong but when I saw two with the same thing, I figured I must have been the crazy one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function () {
   $(this).next("label").children("img").toggleClass("selected", this.checked);
});
```

If the position of the label can change, then you can find the correct associated label based on `name`:

```
$("[for=" + this.name + "]").children("img")
   .toggleClass("selected", this.checked);
```

Comment: Gonna go ahead and vote you correct because you need the rep more. ;) However, Using $(":checkbox") evaluates to $("*:checkbox"), so it parses all elements. I will be using a variation of this so it only looks at inputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).next('label').children('img').addClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        $(this).next('label').children('img').removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

`next(selector)` gets the next sibling *iff* it matches the selector. Obviously the above code only works if the structure of your HTML is always like that.

Reference: [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/), [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)